# How to access contacts list in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, contacts

How do you access the contacts store (the contact list) within Windows Phone 7?

Thanks!

**update**: It seems that this might be available in the next version of WP7, Mango:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140601071021/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/johnalioto/archive/2011/04/13/10153420.aspx)

Comment: There was a way to access the contacts in the Windows phone... Please refer the below blog... http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2012/04/how-to-retrieve-phone-number-from.html I hope this would help you to solve the problem..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

EDIT: This answer was correct at the time of posting. In Windows Phone 7.1 (Mango) third-party applications will have access to contacts.

---

You can't. You're not allowed to. That's viewed as private data that applications shouldn't be touching.

EDIT: Although you can't directly access the contacts list, you *can* launch the [`EmailAddressChooserTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.emailaddresschoosertask(VS.92).aspx) or [`PhoneNumberChooserTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.phonenumberchoosertask(v=VS.92).aspx) to get back just that piece of information about a *user-specified* contact. (Likewise you can launch a task to save a phone number or email address.)

Comment: Jon, any idea if in the future they'll allow developers to access that data?

Comment: @Andrei: Absolutely no idea, I'm afraid.

Comment: Personally, I hope they don't, I don't want apps to have access to my contact list. Especially if they also want web access.

Comment: Just a note, that this is no longer a valid answer. In 7.1, Mango, thirdparty apps will have read only access to the phones contacts.

Answer (score 6):

There is a [official Walkthrough at Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286414%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) especially for Mango Beta 2.

> Windows Phone SDK 7.1 Beta 2 gives you read-only access to the user’s contact data, aggregated across the user's different accounts.

Only possible way to save new details to a contact is via the Launchers:

- SaveEmailAddressTask
- SavePhoneNumberTask
- SaveContactTask (which is new to Mango Beta 2)

For read only you can use:

- PhoneNumberChooserTask
- EmailAddressChooserTask
- AddressChooserTask (which is new to Mango Beta 1)

If you want to query the whole contact list, you will need LINQ.

Comment: Could you provide some reference on how can you "query whole contact list" by my custom application through LINQ? As far as I recall, "accessing the list as whole" is completely impossible and this is why the "Choosers/Composers" were introduced

Comment: Sure thing. Please take a look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286416(v=vs.105).aspx). They are filtering the complete list and set the filter to none: "In this procedure, you set the filter kind to None, which returns all contacts."

Comment: Very strange.. I worked on 7.0, 7.1 an 7.5 but I do not recall the whole `PhoneDataSharingContext` class tree (I mean, `Contacts` class, Appointments came IIRC with 8.0) to be visible. I must have missed it somehow. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

Check the [WP7.1 SDK Beta](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=213054&S=MA) for the class "Contacts" listed in the namespace UserData . Now you should be able to...