# Can i access and update sim contacts in windows phone 7 application

Tags: windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access contacts list in Windows Phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107139/how-to-access-contacts-list-in-windows-phone-7)

I just start learning windows phone 7. So I want to know can i access and then update and delete my sim contacts or phone contacts in windows phone 7 application. If yes then please specify some details

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107139/how-to-access-contacts-list-in-windows-phone-7